# Magento 2: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: magento2, php, performance

I'm running my custom script on Magento 2. It gives below error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 139
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 139
```

Do I need to set

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '6G');
```

?

On the start of script or need to change in php.ini

Comment: You can change in start of your script.

Comment: Hi @RakeshJesadiya i need to put ini_set in start of my script right?

Comment: Yes you have to keep it start of script

Answer (score 2):

Change the setting in php.ini and restart server.  There is no need to change in code or put in start of file because best solution is to do in php.ini.

You can also try in .htaccess.

Comment if face issue again. I will help you to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in app/bootstrap.php.
bootstrap.php is included in cron, frontend, api.

Answer (score -1):

From cli you can do: php -d memory_limit=4G ....
From web request you should just write better code. There is no need for a webserver to use more than 8Mb of memory.

Comment: 8Mb, seriously :)

Comment: Ofcourse, if your page is 200Kb than you only have a overhead of 3200%. That would normaly be enough for a Php Script Kiddy. But yeah, your right. Not for all of them 3200% is enough overhead.